# Deployment items in .runsettings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I am migrating a large solution from VS 2010 to VS 2013. We have a few thousand tests that do not run when we use a .runsettings file. Our previous test settings file was of the .testsettings type. My understanding (after much frustrated Googling) is that in order to use the new test runner VSTest you need to use a .runsettings file. I haven't been able to find much documentation on what this file can support. This is basically the one resource available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx

Our previous .testsettings file had a large section for deployment items that now cannot be found and thus the tests fail immediately. The problem is I can't seem to find out if including deployment items is still an option in a .runsettings file.

```
<Deployment>
  <DeploymentItem filename="C:\Solution\Project\SomeSettings.xml" outputDirectory="C:\Solution\Project\bin" />
</Deployment>
```

Does the new .runsettings test settings format support doing deployment items?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.runsettings` does not support deployment items the same way as with `.testsettings` unfortunately, and I for one find this very frustrating as it was a very clean way of deploying dependencies.  There is a setting related to it in `.runsettings` (`DeploymentEnabled`), but all this seems to control is running tests in a separate directory, rather than the application's output directory.

After much trial and error, I ended up just changing all the `.csproj` files in my test projects to have a `CopyIfNewer` build action in the Properties window in Visual Studio so that all the dependencies would be copied into the output folder so they'd be found when running the tests.

I think all told I spent about 2-3 hours updating all the tests to get them running again.

On the plus side, things run a lot faster now as there's no need to copy all the binaries to a new directory after they are compiled, as everything runs "in-place".

Comment: I have a similar issue here, but couldn´t understand exactly your solution.

I´d need to copy multiple folders that I´d wish to copy. These folders are on related dlls rather than on the test project itself.

How Should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to either manually add everything you need copying to the project file (e.g. as a linked item), or create a custom MSBuild post-build action to copy them to the location you need them in.

Comment: Thanks martin.

In the end, I was able to solve it, on my scenario by using the [DeploymentItem] attributes and creating a base class to be extended by my tests.

Took some time to figure the right relative paths, but worked fine.